# Solution of the ordinary differential equation $y'(t)=-y^3+y^2+2y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the solution of the ordinary differential equation $y'(t)=-y^3+y^2+2y$ subject to $y(0)=y_0 \in (0,2). $ then $\lim \limits_{t \to \infty}y(t)$ belongs to

1. {-1,0}
2. {-1,2}
3. {0,2}
4. {0, $+\infty $}

My Attempt:  $y'(t)=-y^3+y^2+2y \\ \Rightarrow y'(t)=-y(y^2-y-2) \\ \Rightarrow y'(t)=-y(y-2)(y+1) \\ \Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dt}=-y(y-2)(y+1) \\ \Rightarrow \frac{dy}{y(y-2)(y+1)}=-dt \\ \Rightarrow \int\frac{dy}{y(y-2)(y+1)}=\int-dt \\by \;\;partial \;fraction \; we \; get \\ \int [\frac{-1}{2y}+\frac{1}{6(y-2)}+\frac{1}{3(y+1)}]dy =-\int dt \\ \Rightarrow -\frac{1}{2} log|y| +\frac{1}{6} log|y-2| + \frac{1}{3} log|y+1|=-t + logc_1 \\ \Rightarrow \frac{-3log|y|+log|y-2|+2log|y+1|}{6}=-t + logc_1 \\ \Rightarrow log\frac{(y-2)(y+1)^2}{y^3}=-6t+6logc_1 \\ \Rightarrow log\frac{(y-2)(y+1)^2}{y^3}-logc_1^6=-6t \\ \Rightarrow log\frac{(y-2)(y+1)^2}{cy^3}=-6t \;\; where \;c_1^6=c \\ \Rightarrow \frac{(y-2)(y+1)^2}{cy^3}=e^{-6t}..........(1) \\ when \;\;t=0 \;\; \frac{(y_0-2)(y_0+1)^2}{y_0^3}=c \\ (1) \Rightarrow \frac{(y-2)(y+1)^2}{y^3}=\frac{(y_0-2)(y_0+1)^2}{y_0^3} e^{-6t}$

Now I am not getting how to apply the limit for this and how to find $\lim \limits_{t \to \infty} y(t)$

Comment: I think it will simply be $0$. By the way, the options provided are sets with discrete elements or intervals?

Comment: No need to compute the exact solution, just sketch the phase portrait directly from the equation $\dot y = -y (y-2)(y+1)$.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh when using $\{$ and $\}$ is is always set of discrete elements and not an interval

Comment: @Holo Then, three of the options will be the answer

Comment: @Hans Lundmark how do I find the limit if I consider only $\dot y=-y(y-2)(y+1)

Comment: @Aniruddha Deshmukh please will you explain how do I get option 3. Because in the key answer it is given that option 2 and 3 are correct

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh no, you will have the Lim of $\frac{(y(t)-2)(y(t)+1)^2}{y(t)^3}=0$, not the Lim of $y(t)=0$

Comment: @Holo Yes! Got it!

Comment: The answer below is correct.

Comment: @Holo But in the key answer it is given that option 2 and 3 are correct then how do we get limit of y(t) =0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you got $\frac{(y-2)(y+1)^2}{y^3}=\frac{(y_0-2)(y_0+1)^2}{y_0^3} e^{-6t}$ take the limit and you get $$\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}\frac{(y-2)(y+1)^2}{y^3}=0\implies \lim\limits_{t\to\infty}(y-2)(y+1)^2=0 \implies \lim\limits_{t\to\infty}y(t)=\begin{cases}2\\-1\end{cases}$$ hence option (2) is true

Comment: Thank you. I thought that y(t) is dependent on t so I can't apply the limit directly to the expression $(y-2)(y+1)^2 $. also in the key answer it is given that option 2 and 3 are correct. how do we get option 3?

Comment: @Priyanka to be clear about the limit, (1) you have to remember that taking the limit means we are taking the variable $t$ and putting in it a "big number", so as long as you don't do anything like $\lim y(t)=y(\lim t)$ without the necessary knowledge you can always take the limit. And if you have $\lim (f(t)=g(t))$ you can do $\lim f(t)=\lim g(t)$ to get to something nicer. About why they gave you also (3) as an answer... I am not sure, I have a little space so I will add another comment about my thought about this

Comment: If both (2) and (3) correct then $(2)\cup(3)$ correct, but $(1)\subset(2)\cup(3)$ so also (1) should be correct. I don't know if they are wrong or I may missing something here

Comment: Since $y_0\in(0,2)$ then $y(t)\in(0,2)$. So $\lim \limits_{t \to- \infty}y(t)=0$ and $\lim \limits_{t \to+ \infty}y(t)=2$.

Answer (score 2):

Given that $$y'(t)=-y^3+y^2+2y=-y\left(y^2-y-2\right)=-y(y-2)(y+1)$$
Clearly at $~y=-1,~0,~2~$ we have $~y'=0~.$
So the direction field will be something like:

[image]

When $~y<-1~,$ slope of $~y~$ is increasing.
When $~-1<y<0~,$ slope of $~y~$ is decreasing.
When $~0<y<2~,$ slope of $~y~$ is increasing.
When $~y>2~,$ slope of $~y~$ is decreasing.

Given that $~y(0)=y_0\in(0,~2)~,$ which implies that $~\lim_{t\to\infty}y(t)=2~.$

Hence **option** $\bf{(2)}$ and **option** $\bf{(3)}$ are the only correct options.

**Note:**  I know that there is an accepted answer of this old question. But One can check that this is an totally new idea.  So I don't think the community should have any objection about it. Thank you.

Comment: Weak suggestion: Can you change the plot so that the constant solutions are asymptotes of the other solutions, that is, make them more sigmoid? As it is it looks like solutions will cross or at least branch.